# find singular point and investigate its type for x^2 y" + (e^x-1)y' +(sin ^2 x)y=0 and Specify the answer form of y1(x), y2(x)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

find singular point and investigate its type for
$$x^2y''+(e^x-1)y'+(sin^2x)y=0$$ and Specify the answer form of $y_1(x)$,$y_2(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Near $x=0$,$e^x-1 \approx x, \sin x \approx x$ one can write the given ODE as:
$$x^2y''+xy'+x^2y=0 \implies y''+\frac{1}{x}y'+y=0$$. So $x=0$,is regular sigular point. By putting $y=x^m$, we get indicial equation as $m^2=0$.
So the both indical roots are zero. By frobbenius mrthod $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ will  infinite series which are well behaved at $x=0$.